# Is there an equivalent to {% include 'ajaxify-cart' %} for javascript? | Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, cart, sidebar, ajaxify

I have a store that's using a sidebar filter to filter products on my collection pages by tags, collections, vendor, and various other options. The filter is written into the **theme.js**

I've added an add to cart button and gone though the procedures listed in this article to "ajaxify" my cart.

https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/add-to-cart/stay-on-product-page-when-items-added-to-cart.

Everything works wonderfully. The filter does what it's supposed to. The add to cart button works in both my collections pages on my home pages and the collection pages with the filter.

The only exception is that the ajaxify-cart.liquid doesn't seem to be triggered  on the collection pages itself, where the sidebar is. Everywhere else is fine.

I'm guessing it's because the ajaxify-cart.liquid isn't being triggered in the sidebar.

I'm wondering if there's some code that can be added to the theme.js to achieve something like what the {% include 'ajaxify-cart' %} does in liquid files.

Am I way off with this? If so, any ideas?

As always, thanks for your time.

Jeff

Comment: Hi Jeff, I think its a javascript conflict issue. Can you share your website url. Regards

Comment: Absolutely.

Here's the [Collection Page (with the sidebar filter)](https://spellbuds-dev.myshopify.com/collections/all/)

and here is the [main page](https://spellbuds-dev.myshopify.com).

Thanks for taking a look! @MashR.

Comment: Hi, On your collection page, the products get loaded using javascript ajax call. That is why the ajaxify does not work on them.

Comment: Can you export the theme and share the file with me. I will try to solve the issue and give you instructions on how to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I fixed the theme and sent you on dropbox.

Comment: The solution with code fixes should be posted as an answer so that others may benefit as well.